# Count the number of deleted rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do i count the number of deleted rows while using Stored procedure in SQL server?
i Tries the Following:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[P_DeleteNames] @xmlDoc nText
as
declare @handle int 
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @handle output, @xmlDoc
create table #deletename(nameId int) 
insert INTO #deletename(nameId)
SELECT NameID
from openxml(@handle,'/dsNames/dtNames',2)
with (nameID int)

set NOCOUNT OFF
set ROWCOUNT 0
delete FROM NamesTable where name_ID in(select nameID from #deletename)  
exec sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

It always returns the number twice the deleted rows. I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[P_DeleteNames] @xmlDoc nText
as
declare @handle int 
declare @countdeleted int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @handle output, @xmlDoc


delete FROM NamesTable where name_ID in(
 SELECT NameID
 from openxml(@handle,'/dsNames/dtNames',2)
 with (nameID int)
)

/* save in a local variable and use it as you wish */
set @countdeleted = @@ROWCOUNT

exec sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

[@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187316.aspx) is a global variable, it ill count the rows affected by the last command.

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT is not global - it returns the number of rows affected by the preceding command in scope. If it was global it would be useless.

Comment: Maybe this is where the name comes from: The names of some Transact-SQL system functions begin with two at signs (@@). Although in earlier versions of Microsoft SQL Server, the @@functions are referred to as global variables, they are not variables and do not have the same behaviors as variables. The @@functions are system functions, and their syntax usage follows the rules for functions

Comment: You are right about the scope, but wrong about it not being global. In the context the term global refers to a "system" (thus global) function acting as variable to differentiate from local declared variables (started with one @) and in fact it's a pattern to name "global variables" with two @@